# SparkContext dataset Json file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I have this JSON file:

```json
{
  "_id": "series/cogtech/Zancanaro12",
  "type": "Article",
  "title": "Shared Interfaces for Co-located Interaction.",
  "pages": {
    "start": 71,
    "end": 88
  },
  "year": 2012,
  "booktitle": "Ubiquitous Display Environments",
  "url": "db/series/cogtech/364227662.html#Zancanaro12",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Massimo Zancanaro"
    }
  ],
  "a": [
    1,
    3,
    5,
    5
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to pass data from a JSON file to a dataset without going through a dataframe. If I have to create a class, How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the json file within project resources folder and read it from there and then use this as per your needs

```
val input_file = "input.json"
val json_content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(input_file).mkString
val json_data = JSON.parseFull(json_content)
```